# Code examples for using sound files in ActionScript3.0 for Flash Pro

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

I'd appreciate seeing some examples of ActionScript 3.0 code that deploys any kind of sound files to be used in Flash Pro files, for final output as SWF.

I am using the code (below) for the Base class of a Bubble Game (of sorts), and the problem is, that when popped, the sound plays a little too late, not spot on.

thanks.
This is my code - which is linked to the Bubbles in the library of my FLA:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class BubbleBaseNew4 extends MovieClip
    {
        var thisBubble:MovieClip;
        var navdock:MovieClip;
        var thisParent:*;
        private var snd:Sound = new Sound();

        public function BubbleBaseNew4()
        {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initialize);//off http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/838/cpsid_83815.html to do ADDED_TO_STAGE instead of ADDED
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pop);
        }

        function initialize(event:Event):void
        {
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initialize);//this causes sym_mc to be defined as an Ojbect

            thisParent = event.currentTarget.parent;
            navdock = thisParent.nav_mc;
            thisBubble = MovieClip(this.parent.getChildByName(this.name));

            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBubble);

            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("my_own_twp_noise_tremolo_phaser_.mp3");
            snd.load(req); 
        }

        function moveBubble(event:Event):void
        {
            if(navdock != null && this.hitTestObject(navdock)) 
            {
                trace("HIT!");
                this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBubble);
                this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pop);
                this.parent.addChild(this);//this adds the bubble that's removed, i think.
                this.parent.removeChild(thisBubble);
            }
            else
            {
                var mc:MovieClip = event.target as MovieClip;
                if(currentFrame == 1)
                {
                    mc.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                    mc.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;

                    rotation += Math.random() * -90;
                }

            }
        }

        function pop(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            /*var bzp:Sound = Sound(thisParent.my_own_twp_noise_tremolo_phaser_.wav);
            this.load(bzp);*/
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initialize);
            this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pop);
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBubble);

            var main:MovieClip = MovieClip(this.parent.parent);
            main.increaseScore();
            //mediary 'increaseScore function' variable
            var main4:MovieClip = MovieClip(this.parent.parent);
            main4.increaseScore4();
            this.parent.removeChild(thisBubble);
            snd.play();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things you could try. The first is to change the mouseEventListener for the pop function from `MouseEvent.CLICK` to `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN`, that way you don't have to wait for a `MOUSE_UP` before the function is called.

The second thing is to make sure the sound file is trimmed down so there is absolutely not one nanosecond of silence at the beginning. [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/) is a good program to use for stuff like that.